# Is there a good way to attach JavaScript objects to HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to associate a JavaScript object with an HTML element. Is there a simple way to do this?

I noticed [HTML DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html) defines a setAttribute method and it looks like this is defined for arbitrary attribute name. However this can only set string values. (You can of course use this to store keys into a dictionary.)

**Specifics** (though I'm mostly interested in the general question):

Specifically, I have HTML elements representing nodes in a tree and I'm trying to enable drag-and-drop, but the jQuery drop event will only give me the elements being dragged and dropped.

The normal pattern for getting information to event handlers seems to be to create the HTML elements at the same time as you are creating JavaScript objects and then to define event handlers by closing over these JavaScript objects - however this doesn't work too well in this case (I could have a global object that gets populated when a drag begins... but this feels slightly nasty).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery, you can use its [data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data#name) method for this. This allows you to assign complex objects to the element if you want or you can leverage that method to hold a reference to an object (or some other data) at the very least.

It's worth noting that, under the hood, jQuery implements `data()` in precisely the way that [bobince described in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402782), so you always use that directly, whether or not you're using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you: This is pretty much what I was looking for.

Interestingly to define this method jquery stores keys into a global dictionary in a string attribute on each element. The name of this string attribute is randomly generated when jquery is first loaded. 

(Suggesting that there isn't a good way to do there isn't a nicer way to do this only using the DOM)

Answer (score 129):

JavaScript objects can have arbitrary properties assigned to them, there's nothing special you have to do to allow it. This includes DOM elements; although this behaviour is not part of the DOM standard, it has been the case going back to the very first versions of JavaScript and is totally reliable.

```
var div= document.getElementById('nav');
div.potato= ['lemons', 3];
```

Comment: @tat.wright - The arbitrary properties on HTML elements he's speaking of are called Expando properties. Also note that div.potato does not mean div.getAttribute("potato")

Comment: It's not totally reliable at all. For example, one call to `document.expando = false` in IE prevents all expando properties on HTML elements within the document.

Comment: @Tim Down: then just don't do it. I fail to see why it isn't reliable - it's like saying that the String object is unreliable, because you can set it to null.

Comment: @simon - not really. There are good reasons for setting `document.expando = false` (e.g. preventing accidental misspellings of DOM properties being silently accepted). Also, IE doesn't allow expando properties on all objects (for example, ActiveX objects such as XMLHttpRequest in IE6, at least).

Comment: ahem - this answer talks about expando being bad as it creates leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4798255/849004 . So - who is right?

Comment: @TimDown: But won't setting `document.expando = false` break [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), too?

Comment: @JoeyAdams: I believe so. I'm not recommending that either :)

Comment: From my experience the reason this can be bad is possible memory leaks.  There might be an easy way to avoid it, but when I made a design that used this heavily it had many memory leaks.  I think you have to be extra careful because reference counting isn't handled for you (not cleaned up) if the element is removed from the page, and probably visa-versa.

Comment: @TimDown: `$.data()` uses this technique, so if this doesn't work, neither will jquery - and jQuery is used rather widely :-).

Comment: @eselk: this was an IE issue that was [fixed in IE8 (!)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361842(v=vs.85).aspx) and is therefore unlikely to affect you anymore; unless, of course, you still support IE7.  Also note that even in IE7 you're fairly safe since leaks are per-page, so unless you constantly make new objects and the page is open a long time, this won't get out of hand.

Comment: `var cloned = div.cloneNode()` makes `potato` go away on `cloned`, while other native attributes does get cloned.

Comment: Fair warning: I was happily doing what the answer describes, but instead of the field name "potato" I was using "scope". Turns out "scope" is an attribute of table cell elements (`<td>`) and the object I assigned to this field was #toString'ed. I was very confused seeing td.scope === '[object Object]'.