# How to store a JavaScript Object caught while debugging for future reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom

Is it possible to add a JavaScript object which is found while debugging, to the DOM for future reference? (It is okay to keep it in any place where retrievable. DOM is just a suggestion. Storing and retrieving needs to be done using a debugging tool.)

(Sample usage:pass as a argument by retrieving it from DOM while calling to a function using console.)

Note : This is not about how to add a JavaScript Object to the DOM within JS code. I'm aware that it can be done using methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402693/is-there-a-good-way-to-attach-javascript-objects-to-html-elements).

Comment: In what form do you want this object in the DOM?

Comment: Why not using the global object window? Should the value be stored for a specific element? Please elaborate.

Comment: @snapjs Assume this is not a simple object. So I want to keep at as a JavaScript object as it is rather than a String.

Comment: @Sagi  I just want to store it globally, not for a specific element. Can you explain further how to add it to the global object window using developer tools since the object can only be found while debugging

Comment: Just open the developer tools, peek the console and type 
window.yourProp = yourValue

Comment: Also if debugging in browser console can store right in console ( right click)

Comment: It is the answer I'm looking for. Thanks @Sagi

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using firefox developer tools and there's no such an option.

Comment: there is in firefox developer version...haven't looked at standard version for long time