# jQuery .remove() vs Node.removeChild() and external maps to DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The jQuery API documentation for jQuery [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) mentions:

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

I assume "bound events" here means "event handlers"; documentation for the similar [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) says:

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.

It does sound like leaks would ensue if one were to **not** use these functions and use [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) (or [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove)) instead.

Is this true for modern browsers?

- If so, why exactly can't properties and event handlers be collected once the node is removed?
- If not, do we still need to use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)? Is it only good to retrieve HTML5 `data-` attributes?

Documentation for [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) (lower-level function) says:

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   free from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that the data is removed when
>   DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves
>   the page.

This sounds an awful lot like a solution to the old IE [DOM/JS circular leak pattern](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index3.shtml) which, AFAIK, is solved in all browsers today.

However, a comment in the jQuery [`src/data.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js) code ([snapshot](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/30eee925dbc9f8d465ccf064f48c24061ffdc378/src/data.js)) says:

> Provide a clear path for implementation upgrade to WeakMap in 2014

Which suggests that the idea of storing data strictly associated to a DOM node outside of the DOM using a separate data store with a map is still considered in the future.

**Is this just for backward-compatibility, or is there more to it?**

Answers provided to other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160193/using-jquerys-datastore-vs-expando-properties) also seem to imply that the sole reason for an external map is to avoid cyclic refs between DOM objects and JS objects, which I consider irrelevant in the context of this question (unless I'm mistaken).

Furthermore, I've seen plugins that now set properties on relevant DOM nodes directly (e.g. [selectize.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js)) and it doesn't seem to bother anyone. Is this an OK practice? It certainly looks that way, as it makes removing entire DOM trees very easy. No need to walk it down, no need to clean up any external data store, just detach it from the parent node, lose the reference, and let the garbage collector do its thing.

#### Further notes, context and rationale to the question:

This kind of capability is especially interesting for frameworks that manage views (e.g. [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)), which often times have to replace entire trees that represent said views in their architecture. While most of them certainly support jQuery explicitly, this solution does not scale at all. Every component that uses a similar data store must also be cleaned up. In the case of Durandal, it seems they (at least in one occurrence, the [dialog plugin](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/src/plugins/js/dialog.js) - [snapshot](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/58cc44791515309bea5a435a8f149c65b0f79a90/src/plugins/js/dialog.js)) rely on Knockout's [`.removeNode()`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.domNodeDisposal.js) ([snapshot](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/ae6856189bb558d5d4b1f4867602045784f5aad5/src/utils.domNodeDisposal.js)) utility function, which in turn uses jQuery's [internal `cleanData()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083884/what-is-the-purpose-of-jquery-clean-and-cleandata-methods). That's, IMHO, a prime example of horrible special-casing (I'm not sure it even works as it is now if jQuery is used in noConflict mode, which it is in most AMD setups).

**This is why I'd love to know if I can safely ignore all of this or if we'll have to wait for [Web Components](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/) in order to regain our long-lost sanity.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"It does sound like leaks would ensue if one were to not use these functions and use Node.removeChild() (or ChildNode.remove()) instead.*
>
> *Is this true for modern browsers?*
>
> *If so, why exactly can't properties and event handlers be collected once the node is removed?"*

Absolutely. The data (including event handlers) associated with an element is held in a global object held at `jQuery.cache`, and is removed via a serial number jQuery puts on the element.

When it comes time for jQuery to remove an element, it grabs the serial number, looks up the entry in `jQuery.cache`, manually deletes the data, and then removes the element.

Destroy the element without jQuery, you destroy the serial number and the only association to the element's entry in the cache. The garbage collector has no knowledge of what the `jQuery.cache` object is for, and so it can't garbage collect entries for nodes that were removed. It just sees it as a strong reference to data that may be used in the future.

---

While this was a useful approach for old browsers like IE6 and IE7 that had serious problems with memory leaks, modern implements have excellent garbage collectors that reliably find things like circular references between JavaScript and the DOM. You can have some pretty nasty circular references via object properties and closures, and the GC will find them, so it's really not such a worry with those browsers.

However, since jQuery holds element data in the manner it does, we now have to be very careful when using jQuery to avoid jQuery-based leaks. This means *never* use native methods to remove elements. Always use jQuery methods so that jQuery can perform its mandatory data cleanup.

---

> *"Furthermore, I've seen plugins that now set properties on relevant DOM nodes directly (e.g. selectize.js) and it doesn't seem to bother anyone. Is this an OK practice?"*

I think it is for the most part. If the data is just primitive data types, then there's no opportunity for any sort of circular references that could happen with functions and objects. And again, even if there are circular references, modern browsers handle this nicely. Old browsers (especially IE), not so much.

---

> ***"This is why I'd love to know if I can safely ignore all of this or if we'll have to wait for Web Components in order to regain our long-lost sanity."***

We can't ignore the need to use jQuery specific methods when destroying nodes. Your point about external frameworks is a good one. If they're not built specifically with jQuery in mind, there can be problems.

You mention jQuery's `$.noConflict`, which is another good point. This easily allows other frameworks/libraries to "safely" be loaded, which may overwrite the global `$`. This opens the door to leaks IMO.

AFAIK, `$.noConflict` also enables one to load multiple versions of jQuery. I don't know if there are separate caches, but I would assume so. If that's the case, I would imagine we'd have the same issues.

---

If jQuery is indeed going to use WeakMaps in the future as the comment you quoted suggests, that will be a good thing and a sensible move. It'll only help in browsers that support WeakMaps, but it's better than nothing.

---

> *"If not, do we still need to use `.data()`? Is it only good to retrieve HTML5 data- attributes?"*

Just wanted to address the second question. Some people think `.data()` should always be used for HTML5 `data-` attributes. I don't because using `.data()` for that will import the data into `jQuery.cache`, so there's more memory to potentially leak.

I can see it perhaps in some narrow cases, but not for most data. Even with no leaks, there's no need to have most `data-` stored in two places. It increases memory usage with no benefit. Just use `.attr()` for most simple data stored as `data-` attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Your explanation of the internal workings of jQuery.cache and your recommendations regarding data- attributes are especially helpful. I recognize my question(s) triggered discussions in many directions, and am having second thoughts as to whether these discussions might belong to jQuery-specific channels rather than SO. However, I'd like to pick your brains a little more: with your knowledge of jQuery, do you think it's possible for jQuery to assign all node-specific data to the nodes themselves in modern browsers only, removing the need for cleanup?

Comment: @tne: I think that they would need to do some testing on all versions of browsers they support before they would feel confident enough, but overall, in modern browsers, I think it's a pretty safe bet. They could still do cleanup with their methods, but let the GC handle the other cases. A couple weeks ago, I tested the GC in Chrome and Firefox by creating some really nasty looking circular references via properties and closures. Basically for each element, everything had some reference to everything else, including itself. Both browsers were able to release the memory successfully.

Comment: I think it would be wise for jQuery to put the data directly on the element, and still do their cleanup. If you think about it, currently no matter what, there *will* be a memory leak if people don't use jQuery methods to remove elements. So it's really no better off than having the data directly on the element itself. At least there's a *chance* that the memory will be released if the data is directly on the element, where there's no chance if it's in `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: ...one caveat may be IE6, where upon closing the browser, memory leaks would persist. I assume jQuery does an `onunload` handler to clean up the `jQuery.cache` manually. But I think that only affects IE6, which just doesn't matter so much at this point.

Comment: That was my thinking exactly; the results of your tests are promising. I think your point about API safety (newbie or confused developers not using jQuery facilities to remove elements) is a very valid point also. I, for one, wouldn't mind letting IE6 leak until window.unload (the nice thing about this situation is that people could still have the choice to care or not). I also had a question I judged too stupid to ask: there's no DOM event triggered on node removals, is there? I can't even find a draft or a mere discussion anywhere, which I find odd, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @tne: There are some DOM Mutation events that were/are supported by some browsers. I think they were replace by DOM Observers or something like that. Either way, older IE didn't support them. Beyond that I don't know much about them. WRT `onunload`, it wouldn't really work unless you had some sort of central cache. So if you were going to support IE6, you'd probably need an approach where its data gets stored in a cache, and other browsers do not.

Comment: Oh there we go ([`MutationObserver`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)), thanks a bunch for that. Polyfill for IE9+ only though, so wouldn't actually help where it should. I think I'm gonna let this all sink in for a little while, then maybe nudge the relevant people eventually -- Unless there's something else I'm missing, it seems to have come down to supporting more straightforward mechanisms for developers who are willing to drop IE6 support. Maybe it's still a tad too soon. [Or maybe not](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown).

Comment: @tne: Perhaps there are other considerations that I'm forgetting, but I think we've pretty much got it covered. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide some of its features, jQuery has its own storage for some things.  For example, if you do

```
$(elem).data("greeting", "hello");
```

Then, jQuery, will store the key `"greeting"` and the data `"hello"` on its own object (not on the DOM object).  If you then use `.removeChild(elem)` to remove that element from the DOM and there are no other references to it, then that DOM element will be freed by the GC, but the data that you stored with `.data()` will not.  This is a memory leak as the data is now orphaned forever (while you're on that web page).

If you use:

```
$(elem).remove();
```

or:

```
$(some parent selector).empty()
```

Then, jQuery will not only remove the DOM elements, but also clean up its extra shadow data that it keeps on items.

In addition to `.data()`, jQuery also keeps some info on event handlers that are installed which allows it to perform operations that the DOM by itself can't do such as `$(elem).off()`.  That data also will leak if you don't dispose of an object using jQuery methods.

In a touch of irony, the reason jQuery doesn't store data as properties on the DOM elements themselves (and uses this parallel storage) is because there are circumstances where storing certain types of data on the DOM elements can itself lead to memory leaks.

---

As for the consequences of all this, most of the time it is a negligible issue because it's a few bytes of data that is recovered by the browser as soon as the user navigates to a new page.

The kinds of things that could make it become material are:

1. If you have a very dynamic web page that is constantly creating and removing DOM elements thousands of times and using jQuery features on those objects that store side data (jQuery event handlers, `.data()` on those elements, then any memory leak per operation could add up over time and become material.
2. If you have a very long running web page (e.g. a single page app) that stays on screen for very long periods of time and thus over time the memory leaks could accumulate.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive clarifications. Reading my question back, I kind of feel bad for not making it more explicit that I was looking for answers regarding why jQuery and other frameworks use parallel storage and, more importantly, whether it's still relevant today (as opposed to how the API should be used and the consequences of not doing so). Hopefully your answer can help other wandering souls ;).

Comment: @tne - That's a good question on whether the parallel storage is still necessary.  I know there were serious issues with references between DOM/JS objects causing garbage collection to fail to properly dispose of objects that should have been cleaned up, but I presume most of those browser GC issues have now been fixed.  jQuery is generally pretty darn good about keeping current, dropping support for older browsers and ripping out legacy stuff that is no longer needed in the latest revisions (e.g. jQuery 2.x ripped out support for IE6,7,8) so it has probably been at least discussed.

Comment: @tne - It would probably take some sleuthing around in jQuery-land so see whether there's a plan to switch `.data()` over to a DOM element custom property or if there are still believed to be issues with that approach.

Comment: @tne - From a framework perspective that might be managing large blocks of content, I can see how you'd have a conundrum because your own management of that content could lead to jQuery leaks if you weren't using the exact same framework as was being used elsewhere on the content.  This seems like an interesting enough theoretical question that it might be worth finding a relevant jQuery developer list and asking about both the future architectural direction for things like jQuery's `.data()` and how they'd suggest you keep jQuery from causing such a leak when you aren't yourself using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, you're spot on; I assume you've read the thread on cookie monster's answer, that's pretty much where the discussion led to as well. I agree that this probably shouldn't be pursued on SO, but on the relevant lists and issue trackers of the libraries involved (it's certainly not limited to jQuery). As I said on the other thread, I'll sleep on it a couple of times, wait for any outstanding issues to popup, then if it's worth it maybe bother whomever is concerned to get specific details. Thanks again for your interest!